this vs this number
I used 'this number' to make it clear that I'm talking about the number 600. But the freelancer who edited my text changed it to 'this'. Is the referent clear if I only use 'this'?

Ballet is the most popular class for those younger than 11, with
around 600 participants. This/This number is double the number of
11-16 year olds taking ballet.


Your freelancer was right. 'This' can only refer to '600 participants'; and we know that '600' is a number without being told; we avoid 'number' appearing twice, which is clumsy. An alternative could be 'This number is double that of 11-16 year olds taking ballet.'

Of course you could have a similar sentence with a different referent e.g. if you changed it to "Ballet is the most popular class for those aged 12, with around 600 participants. This is double the age of the typical tap dancer." But if you say "X is double Y" then it strongly suggests X and Y belong to the same type of measurement. ("John's age is twice the number of people taking ballet" is unlikely to occur except as the start of a mathematical puzzle.)

Strange that the comment by Michael Harvey gets upvoted , while saying the same in answer gets downvoted ! May be we want to encourage answering in comments !

@Prem - perhaps because my comment says, essentially, the same as your answer, but in fewer words? Also your capitalisation is a little eccentric (pool and percentage are not proper nouns).

Is it the Policy here to answer in comments , @MichaelHarvey , to not elaborate , to not give more variations ? OP can not mark your comment with the green tick mark. Now going by your logic , when you convert the comment to answer , would the Policy be to downvote because it was already in comment ? [[ To be clear , I have no issues with getting downvoted , I am only highlighting the "silliness" in upvotng & downvoting the same content , though it has been reverted ]]

The freelancer who edited the text versus you as a full-time employee? How is being a freelancer relevant?

The Second Sentence requires "number" (or something similar) at least once. Using it twice is grammatically right , though it is clumsy & we generally want to avoid repetition.
Consider this variation :

Ballet is the most popular class for those younger than 11, with around 600 participants in a Pool of 1000 students.
This number is double the number of 11-16 year olds taking ballet. [[ unnecessary repetition makes it longer & clumsy ]]
This number is double that of 11-16 year olds taking ballet. [[ Suggestion by Michael Harvey ]]
This is double the number of 11-16 year olds taking ballet. [[ Suggestion by your freelancer ]]
This is double that of 11-16 year olds taking ballet. [[ Confusing / unclear / ambiguous ]]

Now , we calculate the Percentage to get 60%.
We might have a pool of 500 students among 11-16 year olds , where 150 participate in Ballet. Percentage calculation gives 30%.

Ballet is the most popular class for those younger than 11, with around 600 participants in a pool of 1000 students.
This percentage is double the percentage of 11-16 year olds taking ballet.
This percentage is double that of 11-16 year olds taking ballet.
This is double the percentage of 11-16 year olds taking ballet.
This is double that of 11-16 year olds taking ballet.

We need to specify what we are comparing , number / percentage / weight / discount / age [[ I just saw the comment by Stuart F ! ]] , though specifying it Exactly once is enough unless you are paid by the word count for writing articles.
SUMMARY :
Specifying "number" (or similar) once in either location is good & sufficient.
Specifying it twice is grammatically right , though stylistically clumsy & not idiomatic.
Not specifying it is logically wrong / uncommunicative / ambiguous.

Why are you using a capital p?

Sometimes I capitalize a word to make it Bold , without making it too bold & sometimes to make More Bold , sometimes , it is copy-paste , sometimes the word is somewhat more important in my "Mental View-Point" [ like the Exactly once highlighted ] sometimes for emphasis , sometimes for something else. Mostly , @Lambie , it is for my easily identifiable uniqueness.

... and you wonder why you get downvotes?

Different People have Different Styles , @MichaelHarvey , up with which , no need to get tight , echoing a British Politician. No worries though. I have seen very "Odd Sentence Structures" used by answerers , some which I like & some which I do not like. I focus on Contents.
